# libvlc: seek issues in IOS

Tags: ios, vlc, seek

how to seek using VLC？？

The demo code as flowing doesn't work either.

/* we need to limit the number of events sent by the slider, since otherwise, the user
     * wouldn't see the I-frames when seeking on current mobile devices. This isn't a problem
     * within the Simulator, but especially on older ARMv7 devices, it's clearly noticeable. */

```
[self performSelector:@selector(_setPositionForReal) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];

VLCTime *newPosition = [VLCTime timeWithInt:(int)(_positionSlider.value * self.mediaItem.duration.intValue)];

[self.timeDisplay setTitle:newPosition.stringValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];

self.timeDisplay.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", NSLocalizedString(@"PLAYBACK_POSITION", @""), newPosition.stringValue];

_positionSet = NO;
[self _resetIdleTimer];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the _setPositionForReal selector on the object where you got that snap from. It will show you how to seek correctly.

The code you posted is only part of the solution to reduce the number of events triggered by the seek slider since libvlc can respond well to them, but current iOS devices are a tad to slow to adapt in a pleasing way.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is that seeking is hard to use with setPosition function.  By the way, Why the VLC eat too much memory(20M-60M) when play a movie. However, Apple's native player just need some memeoy between 2M and 5M /**
 * Set movie position. This has no effect if playback is not enabled.
 * \param movie position as percentage between 0.0 and 1.0.
 */
- (void)setPosition:(float)newPosition;